# QScriptEngine evaluate square or cube of number c++

Tags: c++, qt

I need to evaluate cube or square of number in QScriptEngine

```
QString expression_string("2 * 2 * 2"); // not like this but 2^3 
QScriptEngine expression;
double my_val=expression.evaluate(expression_string).toNumber();
```

how to implement 2 * 2 like 2 ^ 2 in this way ?

Answer (score 1):

If you're OK with using the `Math.pow` function directly, then you should just use it: `auto expression = QStringLiteral("Math.pow(2, 3)")`.

If you want to rewrite an expression like `2^3` to be valid javascript, you need a parser. You'd be rewriting the infix syntax `expr1^expr2` to prefix syntax `Math::pow(expr1, expr2)`. This *cannot* be done by a simple regexp.

The parser could be written in JavaScript itself. Perhaps you could reuse [jsep](http://jsep.from.so/annotated_source/jsep.html), modified to take the exponentiation operator, and use it to create an AST of the expression, and then you can either rewrite it to become valid javascript with `Math.pow` *or* evaluate it based on the AST.

jsep makes it trivial to add custom operators - this example is straight from their README:

```
jsep.addBinaryOp("^", 10);
```